# Rig in different postition when I copy keyframe information form one rig to another

Tags: keyframes

[image: **enter image description here**]Ok heres my problem. Hopefully it will probably be a quick fix for one of you. I don't really know how to take screenshots either but I will try to explain my problem clearly.
EDIT ADDED IMAGE

1. I have a basic bouncing ball animation, keyframes all set, it looks good.
2. I'm trying to transfer keyframe information onto a new ball rig. I copy and paste the keyframes, and almost everything works, EXCEPT The NEW rig does NOT follow the same path and information as my old rig it it slightly lower down on my graph, but the animation and movement is all still the same. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Im on mac control f3 doesn't work

Comment: The animation plays all the same its just much lower on my graph can someone explain? I assume its some sort of location issue but I don't know how to offset it.